# get all the text inside HTML span tag and clustering it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML text like:

```
<span class="c1" > text1  text2  text3 </span> text4 text5 text6...
<span class="c2" > text8  text9  text10 </span> text14 text15 text16...
<span class="c1" > text18  text19  text20 </span> text21
```

I would like to have a result like that:

C1: text1  text2  text3 + text18  text19  text20

C2: text8  text9  text10

which mean clustering text by span
How can i do this in Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic solution, if there're more then `c1` and `c2`:

```
var cs = $('span[class^="c"]');
var r = {};

cs.each(function() {
    var e = $(this);

    if (!r[e.attr('class')]) {
        r[e.attr('class')] = '';
    }

    r[e.attr('class')] += e.text();
});

alert (r.c1);
alert (r.c2);
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/mjovohnh/)

Comment: Works very well, thank you. How can I transfert 'r.c1' to php variable is it array?

Comment: @ouss88 You could use this JavaScript: `var json = JSON.stringify(r)` and in PHP `json_decode($json)` - [see the result](http://jsfiddle.net/gdfsz369/)

Comment: thanks once again, just one more question, because your solution seems the most optimal, when I try it in my text I got all text of same class concatenated. I would like to have some thing like c1: text1 text2 text3 || text18 text19 text20 . I mean add separation between text3 and text 18

Comment: @ouss88 You can simply turn the string concatenation into an array. [Take a look at this updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2vvbe9d2/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you want to do have it done in jquery (as you have tagged jquery):

```
var spanText;
    $(".c1").each(function(){
      spanText+=$(this).text();
});
console.log(spanText);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var t1;
$('.c1').each(function(){
    t1 += $(this).text();
});
var t2;
$('.c2').each(function(){
    t2 += $(this).text();
});
console.log('C1: ' + t1);
console.log('C2: ' + t2);
```

```html
<span class="c1" > text1  text2  text3 </span> 
<span class="c2" > text8  text9  text10 </span> 
<span class="c1" > text18  text19  text20 </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS:

```
// pass in a selector
function getText(selector) {

    // grab the elements specified by the selector
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    // return the text from each element
    // [].slice.call is used because `spans` is only "array-like"
    // and we need to convert it to a proper array to make use of `map`
    return [].slice.call(spans).map(function (el) {
        return el.innerHTML;
    }).join('');
}

getText('span.c1'); //  text1  text2  text3  text18  text19  text20 
getText('span.c2'); //  text8  text9  text10
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dp4utn9j/)